# Простой Button Class

Tags: sdl, button, классы, c++

Здравствуйте!

Мне нужен простой, не зависящий ни от чего, кроме SDL2, класс button.

Нужно реализовать вызов функций во время событий onClick и onHover. Есть ли какой-то туториал или уже существующий маленький класс?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ок, разобрался:

```
class button{
public:
    button(int nx, int ny, int nw, int nh, void (*nc)());
    ~button();
    int getX(){ return x; };
    int getY(){ return y; };
    int getW(){ return w; };
    int getH(){ return h; };
    void setX(int nx){ x = nx; };
    void setY(int ny){ y = ny; };
    void setW(int nw){ w = nw; };
    void setH(int nh){ h = nh; };
    void check(SDL_Event *event);
    wigetState getState(){ return state; };
private:
    int x;
    int y;
    int h;
    int w;
    wigetState state;
    void (*callBack)();
};

button::button(int nx, int ny, int nw, int nh, void (*nc)())
{
    x = nx;
    y = ny;
    w = nw;
    h = nh;
    state = MOUSEOUT;
    callBack = nc;
}

button::~button()
{

}

void button::check(SDL_Event* event)
{
    int mx, my;
    SDL_GetMouseState(&mx, &my);
    switch(event->type){
        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if(mx >= x && mx <= x + w && my >= y && my <= y + h){
                state = PRESSED;
            }
            break;
        case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
            if(mx >= x && mx <= x + w && my >= y && my <= y + h){
                state = MOUSEENTER;
            }
            else
                state = MOUSEOUT;
            break;
        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP: if(mx >= x && mx <= x + w && my >= y && my <= y + h){ state = MOUSEENTER; callBack(); }break;
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
button Button(0, 0, 100, 30, onCallBack());
...
в цикле
...
Button.check(&event);
if(PauseMenuButtons[0].getState() == MOUSEOUT) onMouseOut(); else onHover();
```